# Bootstrap 3 CSS - fixed navbar causes a lot of white space on short pages

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sticky-footer

Following [this](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/) example from the official documentation, i noticed that on pages who are going to be < 2000px in height, i will have a lot of white space below the footer.

I can't specify the height of the footer as per [this](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/) example (it might increase dynamically) so i guess i can't stick it to the footer?

How to work around this?

Comment: Could you create a Plunkr or something similar to show what you are trying to do? The example you are linking to does not have a footer so it is not clear, to me at least, what exactly your problem is.

Comment: I'm tryin to achieve this: [link](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/) but i can't specify an height for the footer. And unfortunately it seems that somebody is here only for downvote and not to help.............thanks for your help @Christina

Comment: Perhaps you could also update the link in your question since it is pointing to a different Bootstrap example and thus makes it more difficult for people to understand your question and help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Boostrap's sticky footer, and for the height of Footer, use this jquery, it checks height of footer and adds it to the html tag.
It runs on page load as well as on Window.resize event, so it works great for Responsive projects.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $("html").css("padding-bottom",$(".footer").outerHeight())
    }),
        $("html").css("padding-bottom",$(".footer").outerHeight()
    );
});
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works too. Unfortunately i can't upvote it as i still don't have enough reputation...

Comment: ok ! But you'll need to change the height of footer in different screen resolutions, if your footer has more details/links, like the StackOverflow footer below, as content will get stacked vertically.
Then you may use this script or manually add custom css using media-queries at different breakpoints.

Comment: I'm experiencing some random issues: when the page loads, the script gives the body a `padding-bottom` of 631px. Correct padding should be 692px at the moment. In fact as soon as i resize the window it calculates again the height and the layout gets fixed. I've put the script inside a `jQuery(document).ready(function($)`, so the dom should completely be fully loaded when the script works. Any idea about this? ONLY in firefox the calculation is always done correctly on the page load.

Comment: found the problem...the correct way to do it is not with document ready but with window load!

Comment: ok, but I haven't faced any such issue with my code. I am using it on few websites, no issues with me

Answer (score 0):

What actually makes the footer stick to the bottom of the page in the example you are linking to in your comment is not the footer height, but the following CSS rules:

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

You can see this for yourself if you view the footer through your browser's developer tools and disable the `height` CSS rule, the footer will continue to be at the bottom of the page.

As far as the body margin is concerned, since your footer does not have a fixed height the only way you can set this is use Javascript to measure the footer and set the body margin on `document.ready`. See the attached example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var footerHeight = $('.footer').height();
  $('body').css('margin-bottom', footerHeight);
});
```

```css
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}


/* Custom page CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */

body > .container {
  padding: 60px 15px 0;
}
.container .text-muted {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.footer > .container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

code {
  font-size: 80%;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Begin page content -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Sticky footer with fixed navbar</h1>
      </div>
      <p class="lead">Pin a fixed-height footer to the bottom of the viewport in desktop browsers with this custom HTML and CSS. A fixed navbar has been added with <code>padding-top: 60px;</code> on the <code>body &gt; .container</code>.</p>
      <p>Back to <a href="../sticky-footer">the default sticky footer</a> minus the navbar.</p>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Actually, that example has also a `body { /* Margin bottom by footer height */ margin-bottom: 60px; }`. So, even if the footer height can be avoided, this margin is still mandatory and can't be specified as the height of the footer is variable. The footer will otherwise cover the container.

Comment: @vismark You're right, I completely missed that. In this case you can measure the footer and set the margin with javascript when the page loads. See my updated answer.

Comment: Works like a charm, Christina! Thank you so much! Just a question at this point: isn't unsafe (for compatibility purposes) to delegate such an important function to Javascript?

Comment: @vismark I don't see why it would be unsafe. If you're worried about browser compatibility with jQuery you just need to choose a version supported by your target browsers. If you're worried about the user completely disabling javascript in their browser I'm guessing that you're going to have much bigger problems in that case... If you wanted to be completely safe in the case no javascript is available you could also set the footer's position with javascript. Therefore at least the footer will not stick to the bottom at all without javascript instead of hiding part of your content.